# Change Chrome Scrollbar Color

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

under ubuntu since chrome came out the scroll bar color is silver and hard to see (the contrast)
is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome Store - [Clear Scrollbar Theme](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ppfdcmehpgiojcjgpclmfnbnpdmcmbgo)

This little extension/theme is designed to improve scrollbars visibility in Linux Chrome.

Colors match Clearlook theme.

It's designed for Linux Chrome, but will work on Windows too.

Answer (score 1):

from [How do i change the scrollbar color?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=079a1b1c64b3cc18&hl=en)

> You may be able to change the scroll
>   bar color from your Windows settings,
>   but that would change all scroll bar
>   colors. They're are no supported theme
>   or skin changers in Chrome yet.  You
>   can get third party skins, but they
>   can cause problems.

I think you got it.